# cxf service endpoint jaxrs for multiple beans

Tags: java, spring, cxf

Is it possible to configure many endpoints with the same address or use one endpoint with many beans?

```
<jaxrs:server id="ServiceAImpl" address="/test">
        <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
            <ref bean="serviceABean"/>
        </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <jaxrs:providers>
        <ref bean ="jsonProvider" />
    </jaxrs:providers>
        <jaxrs:extensionMappings>
            <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
            <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
        </jaxrs:extensionMappings>
        <jaxrs:features>
            <cxf:logging/>
        </jaxrs:features>
    </jaxrs:server>
 <jaxrs:server id="serviceBImpl" address="/test">
        <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
            <ref bean="serviceBBean"/>
        </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <jaxrs:providers>
        <ref bean ="jsonProvider" />
    </jaxrs:providers>
        <jaxrs:extensionMappings>
            <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
            <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
        </jaxrs:extensionMappings>
        <jaxrs:features>
            <cxf:logging/>
        </jaxrs:features>
    </jaxrs:server>
```

Either configure as above, or I use only one endpoints but with two beans. The problem with this solution though is that I don't have access to the webservice in the first bean.

```
<jaxrs:server id="serviceImpl" address="/test">
        <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
            <ref bean="serviceABean"/>
            <ref bean="serviceBBean"/>
        </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <jaxrs:providers>
        <ref bean ="jsonProvider" />
    </jaxrs:providers>
        <jaxrs:extensionMappings>
            <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
            <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
        </jaxrs:extensionMappings>
        <jaxrs:features>
            <cxf:logging/>
        </jaxrs:features>
    </jaxrs:server>
```

Which is the correct way to use ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use both equivalently

```
<jaxrs:server id="ServiceAImpl" address="/test/a">
<jaxrs:server id="ServiceBImpl" address="/test/b">

<jaxrs:server id="serviceImpl" address="/test">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="serviceABean"/>  <!--  /test/a service -->
        <ref bean="serviceBBean"/>   <!--  /test/b service -->
```

but it is not allowed

```
<jaxrs:server id="ServiceAImpl" address="/test">
<jaxrs:server id="ServiceBImpl" address="/test">
```